# Slicing numeric value from a categorical column's text

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe where one of the columns is like this:

```
Rating
4.8 out of 5 stars
4.0 out of 5 stars
4.5 out of 5 stars
```

and I want to slice this data keeping only the first number, e.g.

```
Rating
4.8
4.0
4.5
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: I want the result as a float, but i dont know which regex use

Comment: Do `df['Rating'].str.replace(...)` with a regex to extract the number. Do you want the result as a string, categorical or float?

Comment: The title *"Slicing a categorical column"* is misleading, that would refer to `df.loc[:, 'Rating']` or just `df['Rating']`. But you mean *"extract field from string column's text"*.

Comment: Also, on SO, you're expected to show some code attempt (posting failing code is ok), not just post the output and say "I want this".  [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @smci then why're you providing an answer?

Comment: @Neither: I was giving the OP the benefit of the doubt that they had tried to code and their code was failing (they might yet post it). Vote-to-close if you think this should be closed.

Comment: @smci then you should delete your previous comment, it's fully contradictory

Comment: i'm not reputable to vote to close.

Comment: @Neither: no it's not, if the OP can post their code attempt which failed. Look, just downvote already, if you think so. This will get auto-closed and auto-deleted in due course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract a field from a string (or categorical) column's text, use [pandas `Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regex:

```
df['Rating'].str.extract('([1-5]\.[0-9])')

     0
0  4.8
1  4.0
2  4.5

df = pd.DataFrame({'Rating': ['4.8 out of 5 stars', '4.0 out of 5 stars', '4.5 out of 5 stars']}, dtype='category')
```

You can tweak that regex if you need, please see the [manpage](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html). It assumes all ratings are a decimal (not integer), and have one decimal place.

Comment: Welcome to SO. On SO, you're expected to post your own some code attempt (posting failing code is ok), not just post the output and say "I want this". [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help). As @Neither also points out.